# Is there a better way to structure multiple one-to-one relationships with the same entity?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Let's say I'm trying to model an airplane with Entity Framework Core (backed by SQL Server) and I've got the following entities:

```
public class Airplane
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AirplaneInformation { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(LeftWing))]
    public int? LeftWingId { get; set; }
    public Wing LeftWing { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RightWing))]
    public int? RightWingId { get; set; }
    public Wing RightWing { get; set; }
}
public class Wing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WingInformation { get; set; }
    public LeftOrRightEnum LeftOrRight { get; set; }
}
```

I have two query use cases: I want to query a list of Airplanes and access the Left/Right wing information, but I also want to query a list of Wings, and get the associated AirplaneInformation. Ideally I'd have a single Airplane navigation property in the Wing entity, since, in my use case, a Wing can only belong to a single Airplane.
As far as I know, that's not possible to do. You actually need a navigation property per Foreign Key relationship.
So I can't do this:

```
public class Wing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WingInformation { get; set; }
    public LeftOrRightEnum LeftOrRight { get; set; }

    public Airplane Airplane { get; set; }
}
```

But I can do this:

```
public class Wing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WingInformation { get; set; }
    public LeftOrRightEnum LeftOrRight { get; set; }

    public Airplane AirplaneForLeftWing { get; set; }
    public Airplane AirplaneForRightWing { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Airplane Airplane => AirplaneForLeftWing ?? AirplaneForRightWing;
}
```

Now this actually works, but I run into Loading issues that I have to resolve with explicit loads. For instance, if I projected the results of the Wing db set into a view model that accessed `Airplane.AirplaneInformation`, I would get a null reference exception because computed properties do not auto-load any associated navigation properties. That means I always have to include

```
query.Include("AirplaneForLeftWing").Include("AirplaneForRightWing")
```

every time I need to perform this query. The alternative is that I don't use a computed Navigation property at all, but that means I still need to resolve which Airplane navigation property to use each time I want to perform a query like this.

Is there a better way to structure these relationships or configure the relationships so that I can just access a single navigation property without having to perform this additional ceremony around the query each time?

Comment: IMHO, I think you are complicating things. Your scenario can be better represented with a one-to-many relationship - an airplane has multiple wings and a wing belongs to a single airplane. A wing itself should know whether its a left or a right. I wouldn't create two one-to-one relation to express that information through the airplane.

Comment: Are the wings independent of the Airplane? for example: can a wing be associated with multiple planes or  is the wing specific to one plane?

Comment: @Fran Each wing can only be specific to one plane.

Comment: @atiyar That makes sense. I guess I wanted to include a constraint that there can only be two wings, but two-to-one relationships don't exist, so a one-to-many relationship is more appropriate than two one-to-one relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I'd model something like this

```
public class Airplane
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AirplaneInformation { get; set; }

    private readonly List<Wing> _wings;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Wing> Wings => _wings.AsReadOnly();

    public Wing LeftWing
    {
        get
        {
            return _wings.SingleOrDefault(w => w.WingLocation == WingLocation.Left);
        }
    }

    public Wing RightWing
    {
        get
        {
            return _wings.SingleOrDefault(w => w.WingLocation == WingLocation.Right);

        }
    }

    public Airplane()
    {
        _wings = new List<Wing>();
    }

    public void AddWing(string information, WingLocation location)
    {
        //check if we already have that wing
        if (_wings.Any(w => w.WingLocation == location))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"${location} wing already exists");
        }

        _wings.Add(new Wing(information, location));
    }
}
public class Wing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WingInformation { get; private set; }

    public WingLocation WingLocation { get; private set; }

    public Wing(string information, WingLocation location)
    {
        WingInformation = information;
        WingLocation = location;
    }
}

public enum WingLocation
{
    Left,
    Right
}
```

Where LeftWing/RightWing are marked Ignore in the ef mapping.  I don't like dirtying up my model with ef constructs, so I'd put it in DbContext under OnModelCreating(). Also note the ReadOnlyCollection so that you have to add wings thought the AddWing() methods so that we can validate that we only have 1 left or right wing.